# Find and replace a time string in Ruby for TaskPaper Logging

Tags: ruby, string

I'm using Brett Terpstra's Ruby script to find and log completed TaskPaper items as found here: https://gist.github.com/ttscoff/1913007

This script searches lines for lines that have tags that look like '@done(YYYY-MM-DD)', and sends those lines to Day One without the @done string.

However, my items also have a tag '@time(HH:MM)' for more specific time stamping. What I would like to do is additionally find the time tag, capture just the HH:MM string, move it to the front of the entry, also without the @time tag.

I know this question is kind of specific, and I have NO experience with Ruby. Been searching and experimenting all afternoon to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to find this pattern in your input

```
1.9.3p429 :001 > s = 'foo bar baz @time(12:00)'
=> "foo bar baz @time(12:00)"
1.9.3p429 :002 > s.scan(/\@time\((\d{1,2}\:\d{2})\)/)
=> [["12:00"]]
```